# C# Regular Expression Reversing Match

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to convert a part of a string which is **substringof('has',verb)** into  **contains(verb,'has')**

As you can see, what is changing is just **substring** to **contains** and the two parameters passed to the function reversed.

I am looking for a generic solution, by using regex. Preferably using tags. i.e once i get two matches, i need to be able to reverse the matches by using $2$1 (This is how i remember doing this in perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression code:

```
var re = new Regex(@"substringof\('([^']+)',([^)]+)\)");
string output = re.Replace(input, @"contains($2, '$1')");
```

[.NET Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EMILvQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
.*?\((.*?),(.*?)\)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU8mH0/1)**

Then you can use a string replacement like this:

```
contains(\2,\1)    or
contains($2,$1)
```

[image]

Btw, if you just want to change the `substringof`, then you can use:

```
substringof\((.*?),(.*?)\)
```